# Angular JS, unable to get handle to rootScope

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.5.x

Below is my routing logic but I am not able to get a handle of the rootScope.
Please can you advise what could be wrong?

UPDATE: I have updated the routing logic as per the answer post below. 
I am still not able to hit the controller.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('icebergApp')
    .config(setupRouting);

setupRouting.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$rootScope'];

function setupRouting($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $rootScope) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/iceberg-ui");
    $stateProvider
        .state('iceberg.reconlist', {
            url: "/iceberg-ui",
            templateUrl: "app/iceberg/reconlist/reconlist.view.html",
            controller: 'ReconListController as vm'
        })

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateChangeStart to '+toState.name+'- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : \n',toState, toParams);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){
        console.log('$stateChangeError - fired when an error occurs during transition.');
        console.log(arguments);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateChangeSuccess to '+toState.name+'- fired once the state transition is complete.');
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading',function(event, viewConfig){
        console.log('$viewContentLoading - view begins loading - dom not rendered',viewConfig);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound',function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateNotFound '+unfoundState.to+'  - fired when a state cannot be found by its name.');
        console.log(unfoundState, fromState, fromParams);
    });
}
}());
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('iceberg.reconlist', ['ui.router']);
myApp.controller('ReconListController', ReconListController);

ReconListController.$inject = ['ReconListService'];

function ReconListController(ReconListService) {
    var vm = this;
}
}());
```

**MODULE**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('icebergApp', [
      'ui.router',
    'iceberg.reconlist'
]);

angular.module('iceberg.reconlist', [     
]);

}());
```

Comment: where is your module icebergApp  of you . I think problem in it

Comment: instead of `module('app')` probably should be `module('icebergApp')`

Comment: Ignore that please, it is icebergApp, I just corrected in above. Was a copy paste error. Still an issue accessing rootScope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rootScope` is not available in `.config()`. Only providers are available there. The thing you must do is splitting your code to put the `$rootScope` part into a `.run` method.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(setupRouting);

setupRouting.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function setupRouting($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/iceberg-ui");
    $stateProvider
        .state('iceberg.reconlist', {
            url: "/iceberg-ui",
            templateUrl: "app/iceberg/reconlist/reconlist.view.html",
            controller: 'ReconListController as vm'
        })


}
}());

angular.module('app').run(setupRoutingEventListeners);

setupRouting.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

function setupRoutingEventListeners($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateChangeStart to '+toState.name+'- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : \n',toState, toParams);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){
        console.log('$stateChangeError - fired when an error occurs during transition.');
        console.log(arguments);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateChangeSuccess to '+toState.name+'- fired once the state transition is complete.');
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading',function(event, viewConfig){
        console.log('$viewContentLoading - view begins loading - dom not rendered',viewConfig);
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound',function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log('$stateNotFound '+unfoundState.to+'  - fired when a state cannot be found by its name.');
        console.log(unfoundState, fromState, fromParams);
    });
}
```

Comment: This works, I am able to hit the rootScope and access the even handlers. But I still don't see the routing working correctly. My routing service does not pass into the controller correctly. I have updated my controller and app.module definition. How can I figure out why it is not hitting my controller.?

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Deblaton Jean-Philippe